# How to skip the set of values to the first td of a table created dinamically from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table with the days of the months that puts values only in one row (day)

I want the first `td` of each `tr`to be empty, however I've been unable to achieve. This is my "working" snippet.

```js
"use strict";
const dias = new Date().getDate();
const dayX = {
    numero: 2,
    values: { par1: 1, par2: 2, par3: 3, par4: 4, par5: 5, par6: 6, par7: 7, par8: 8, par9: 9, par10: 10 }
};
let objvalforin = dayX.values;
let arr = [];
for (const key in objvalforin) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(objvalforin, key)) {
        const element = objvalforin[key];
        arr.push(element);
    }
}
for (let index = 0; index < dias; index++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = "";
        td.id = index;
        if (td.innerText == "") {
            td.classList.add("tdVacia");
        }
        if (parseInt(td.id) === dayX.numero) {
            td.innerHTML = arr[j];
        }
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    document.getElementById("allDays").appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
td, th {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tdVacia {
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Typescript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="contenedor"></p>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <td>date</td>
            <th>param 1</th>
            <th>param 2</th>
            <th>param 3</th>
            <th>param 4</th>
            <th>param 5</th>
            <th>param 6</th>
            <th>param 7</th>
            <th>param 8</th>
            <th>param 9</th>
            <th>param 10</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="allDays">

        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your array start with an empty value for the first td, then increase your for..loop

```
let arr = [' '];
```

Then

```
...
for (let j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
 ...
```